# Angular: returning a value from onValue() in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I would like to return the "User" object.

Got error message:

> Variable 'user' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

I tried to use async / await but I can't assign await to "return user" at the end of the code or `user= await snapshot.val()` because it is located on `onValue()` scope.

```
getLoggedInUser(id: string): User {
  const db = getDatabase();
  var user: User;
  onValue(ref(db, '/users/' + id), (snapshot) => {
    user = snapshot.val();
    // ...
  }, {
    onlyOnce: true
  });
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call `onValue` you get the current value from that path in the database, and then also get all updates to that value. Since your callback may be called multiple times, there is no way to return a single value.

If you want to just get the value once and return it, you'll want to use `get` instead of `onValue`. Then you can also use `async`/`await`.

```
async getLoggedInUser(id: string): Promise<User> {
  const db = getDatabase();
  var user: User;
  const snapshot = await get(ref(db, '/users/' + id))
  user = snapshot.val();
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! It rerurns promise<User> of course that is easy to handle.

Comment: Good point about the return value.  --- I updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually having a similar issue, although I try to fetch data with paging logic.
We do have thousands of records and to render them nicely (10 - 25 per page) would be the best option anyhow.

```
const dbRef = query(ref(database, folder), orderByChild(field), startAt(start), limitToLast(limit))
return onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    const values = Object.values(snapshot.val());
    return {data: values, total: values.length, page: page}
    })
```

I can see the values inside the onValue, but it seems not to return the value at all. I'm not sure where to go here, the documentation on that is not completely clear to me (a beginner as a developer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31406788)

Comment: Because onValue subscribes to a certain path in your realtime database (to watch for changes), the return value of onValue is an unsubscribe function that you call when you want to stop watching for changes. This is useful, for example, in React when you are unmounting a component.

Simply returning data, total, and page would do nothing; your callback function (the function within onValue) will just operate on the data. This is beyond the scope of this question, but you may need to learn some asynchronous programming - you are never sure exactly when onValue will receive data.